# Cannot invoke <function> with an argument list of type Dictionary<Generic, Generic>

Tags: xcode, swift, generics, swift2, xcode7-beta6

I have a function with the following signature:

```
static func dictionaryToJSON<K : ToJSON,V : ToJSON> ( dictionary : Dictionary<K,V>) -> JValue
```

You can find it [here](https://github.com/PKAuth/SwiftAeson/blob/master/Pod/Classes/SwiftAeson.swift#L133).

When I attempt to call this function, I get the error `Cannot invoke 'dictionaryToJSON' with an argument list of type '(Dictionary<Domain, Account>)'`. Here is the call:

```
let accounts : JValue = Aeson.dictionaryToJSON( self.accounts)
```

`self.accounts` has type `Dictionary<Domain,Account>`, and Domain and Account both implement the protocol `ToJSON`. Is there any reason why this doesn't type check? This is for Swift 2 (XCode 7 beta 6), so maybe there is a compiler bug?

Comment: Does your Domain type implement the Hashable protocol? That is a requirement to be a key in a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, Domain implements Hashable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I commented out Domain's implementation of ToJSON to debug and forgot. It's working now.